# How to load test a Spring application acting as a Kafka consumer?

Tags: spring, jmeter, load-testing, gatling, stress-testing

I have developed a Spring application that serves as a Kafka consumer. It listens to a specific Kafka topic and processes incoming messages. Now, I would like to perform load testing on this application to determine its scalability and performance.

My goal is to understand how many loads of Kafka messages my application can handle efficiently. I want to simulate a high volume of messages (I can do that using jMeter or Gatling) to see if the application can handle the load without any performance degradation or failures.

I have considered using tools like JMeter or Gatling for load testing, but I'm unsure about the specific steps and configurations required for testing a Spring application acting as a Kafka consumer.
Actually the existing solutions using those tools test the Kafka infrastructure itself and not the application.

Here are the main aspects I would like assistance with:

- Is there any tools or frameworks for load testing a Spring
  application acting as a Kafka consumer?
- And if I will need to implement my own tool or plugin, what will be
  the key performance metrics I should measure and analyze during the
  load test to assess the application's scalability?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution is use JMeter or Gatling to simulate upstream application or service which is sending messages to Kafka.

Start with 1 message and gradually increase the load until messages start queuing up which means that your Spring application cannot process them at the speed they're arriving. Analyze the root cause of the issue using profiler tools like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) and fix it. Repeat the test until you're happy with your Spring application performance.

Neither JMeter nor Gatling support Kafka out of the box, you will have to use plugins like:

- [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box/blob/master/README.md) for JMeter, see [How to Do Kafka Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/kafka-testing) for details
- [Gatling Kafka Plugin](https://github.com/Tinkoff/gatling-kafka-plugin),

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, in my case, I am looking for an alternative approach to load testing a Spring application acting as a Kafka consumer. I am unable to utilize profiling tools as I will be testing on a production environment with multiple instances of this application.

I have been considering a method where I generate Kafka messages (Using Gatling) and then verify if the application consumes them correctly based on the offset or some other reliable indicator and generate reports. However, I haven't yet found a reliable way to implement this approach.